# How to transform a Neo4j Query to a GraphQL query?

Tags: javascript, database, neo4j, request, graphql

I'm new on stack overflow and I really think that you can help me.

I started few days ago to work on **NEO4J** and **graphQL**.
In the following code, my neo4j request works without problems. 
About graphQL, I think I made a mistake because, the result after the graphQL request is null.

[Screen of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7vkv.png)

For notes, I'm using :

- https://github.com/philippkueng/node-neo4j
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-es6-graphql

Anyone have an idea ?

```
`
//exampleToNeo4j.js
var neo4j = require("node-neo4j");
var db = new neo4j("http://user:pass@localhost:7474");
class Examples {
    findAll = function(){
    const cypher = "MATCH (a:Article) RETURN a";
    var resultat = db.cypherQuery(cypher.function(err, result){
        if(err) throw err;  
        var resultInt = [];
        for (var i=0; i<result.data.lenght; i++){
            resultInt[i]=result.data[i]._id:
        }
        return resultInt
    }
    return resultat;
    }
}
Export default Examples;

//example.js
import {
GraphQLInterfaceType,
GraphQLObjectType,
GraphQLSchema,
GraphQLString,
GraphQLInt,
GraphQLFloat,
GraphQLList,
GraphQLNonNull} from 'graphql';
import Examples from '../../lib/exampleToNeo4j';
const examples = new Examples();

const exampleType = new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'exampleType',
        description: 'Example description',
        fields: () => ({
        id: {
            description: "Example ID",
            type: GraphQLInt
        }
    })
})
;

const getAllExample = {
        description: 'Have all nodes',
        type: new GraphQLList(exampleType),
        resolve: (root)=>{
            return examples.findAll();
        }

};

export const getAllExamples = getAllExample;
```

`

Comment: I just noticed there is a typo "lenght" in `for (var i=0; i<result.data.lenght; i++){`, does that fix it?

Comment: Let me know if you have a good solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

So, I hope this code helps.
Some point of correction and attention:

The connection is pointing to the wrong default port, you have to use the "bolt" to the other "http", these are the two ports you can connect for example:
*Db = new neo4j ('http: // neo4j: neo4j @ localhost: 7474');*
or
*Var driver = neo4j.driver ("bolt: // localhost: 7687")*

Also be careful with the callback, if not you are required to put a "**setTimeout**" in order to function;
Another thing in the method
"*Db.cypherQuery (cypher, getReturn)*" it does not return so it puts in getReturn as a **callback**;
And not forgetting that JS is **asynchronous**;

I hope it helps. I used it here and it worked out just something that just called me.

```
//example.js
var GraphQL = require('graphql')
var Examples  = require('./exampleToNeo4j.js')

var express = require('express')
var app = express()

const exampleType = new GraphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'exampleType',
        description: 'Example description',
        fields: () => ({
        id: {
            description: "Example ID",
            type: GraphQLInt
        }
    })
})
const getAllExample = {
        description: 'Have all nodes',
        type: new GraphQL.GraphQLList(exampleType),
        resolve: (root)=>{
            return Examples.findAll(root)
        }
};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    getAllExample.resolve(function (data){
        console.log(data)
        res.send(data)
    })

})

app.listen(3000)
console.log('porta 3000')



//exampleToNeo4j.js
var neo4j = require("node-neo4j");
var db = new neo4j("http://localhost:7474");
var Examples = {
    findAll: function(call){
        const cypher = "MATCH (a:Article) RETURN n LIMIT 2"        
        db.cypherQuery(cypher, getReturn)        
        function getReturn(err, result){
            if(err) throw err;            
            var resultInt = [];
            for (var i=0; i<result.data.length; i++){
                resultInt[i]=result.data[i]._id
            }
            //console.log(result)
            call(resultInt)
        }
    }
}
module.exports = Examples;
```